# IntelliJ cant see npm plugins

Tags: intellij-idea, npm, karma-runner

My IntelliJ is not seeing my karma plugins:

```
WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-ng-extjs-scenario".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-ng-extjs-scenario --save-dev
WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-jasmine".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-chrome-launcher".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-firefox-launcher".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-firefox-launcher --save-dev
```

I believe it is because i was following a tutorial that told me to install them globally.
But then i realised that i wanted to install them locally and save to the package.json.
I try again to install locally and it doesnt fix it:

```
$ npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
npm WARN package.json karma-ie-launcher@0.1.5 No README data
info trying registry request attempt 1 at 21:06:11
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine
http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine
karma-jasmine@0.1.5 ../../../node_modules/karma-jasmine
```

I can however run karma from within my project from the command line and the plugins exist in the npm modules directory.

Is there a way to fix this or do i need to reinstall the packages from scratch? 
If so, what is the easiest way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [--link flag](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html) linked the global install into the local directory.

```
npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev --link
```

Comment: Worked for me too ! Maybe you should accept it as an answer :)